# How to check iPhone keyboard klick sound turned on/off in settings?

Tags: iphone

I'm working on custom keyboard and need to play tap sound for keys if it enabled in the Settings. Tap sound not a problem but how to check is keyboard click sound enabled ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make the perfect solution, you should add the following lcode to your app.
Otherwise after the first read, the setting is cached, and if the user switches to settings, makes change and switches back, we should re-read the cached value. :)

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(CFSTR("/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.sounds"));
```

If someone tells me how to comment on this site I would really become more helpful.

Comment: Frustratingly, this doesn't seem to work on iOS 6.0.1. My app seems to cache the setting value that was selected whenever the app first loads. If I change the setting and switch back to my app, it does not adjust. If I force quit my app and restart, the change is picked up. I now have a dilemma: don't provide key clicks in my custom keyboard at all, or live with the bug that settings changes whilst my app is suspended will be ignored. Which is worse?

Comment: I checked on 6.1.4, my app always gets both vars false from `Boolean keyExistsAndHasValidFormat = false;
    bool value = CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue(
                                           CFSTR("keyboard"),
                                           CFSTR("/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.sounds"),
                                           &keyExistsAndHasValidFormat);` So my code stopped playing clicks long ago. So be it, if users complain, I will direct them straight to Apple. We lost the fight.

Answer (score 17):

There's no documented way to check this, but it's possible. I don't know if this really counts as "private API", so be prepared for rejection if you use this method.

The keyboard click sound settings is stored in the shared `com.apple.preferences.sounds` preference. So you could try

```
return CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue(
        CFSTR("keyboard"),
        CFSTR("/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.sounds"),
        NULL);
```

(BTW: the actual call to play the "click" sound in UIKit is `[UIHardware _playSystemSound:1104];`)

Comment: The CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue call works perfectly, but UIHardware isn't recognised (or anywhere in the docs) for me. Instead, I added the AudioToolkit framework and called `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound( 1104 )` for the same effect.

Comment: @Kris: That's because UIHardware is a private class.

Comment: Has anyone submitted an app using `CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue` and this setting and got it approved?