# How can we check if iPhone keyboard click sound is turned on/off in settings in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I want to have click sounds when pressing keys in my keyboard extensions, but only if that preference is enable in iOS Settings. This was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704074/how-to-check-iphone-keyboard-klick-sound-turned-on-off-in-settings), but the answer (adapted for Swift 3)

```
var keyExistsAndHasValidFormat: DarwinBoolean = true
let isKeyboardClickSoundEnabledByUser = CFPreferencesGetAppBooleanValue(
    "keyboard" as CFString,
    "/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.sounds" as CFString,
    &keyExistsAndHasValidFormat
);
```

works in iOS 9 but not in iOS 10 – `keyExistsAndHasValidFormat` always returns false. If you want to test it, use a real device instead of the simulator.

Apple has recently [restricted the shortcuts for Settings](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/10/ios-10-no-longer-lets-you-open-settings-shortcuts-from-widgets.html), but I'm not sure if that affects reading the preferences. Maybe the path has changed?